# Spring Security OAuth2 JWT save last login date

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

As the title states, I want to save/update user's last login date. I'm using spring security oauth2 JWT with both AuthorizationServer/ResourceServer in the same app.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is how I'm doing it currently:

```
@EventListener
public void authSuccessEventListener(AuthenticationSuccessEvent authorizedEvent){
    Authentication authentication = authorizedEvent.getAuthentication();
    if (authentication instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof SecurityUserDetails) {
        // save last login date
        GenericUser genericUser = repositoryService.findByEmail(authentication.getName());
        genericUser.setLastLoginDate(Instant.now());
        repositoryService.save(genericUser);
    }
}
```

SecurityContext isn't fully populated at this point, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns client app's Authentication object. This is a problem if you are doing database auditing.

AuthenticationSuccessEvent triggers every time I login or access a JWT token protected resource. To be more precise, it triggers twice on successful /login, once for client app authentication, and once for user authentication. 
The if() checks are needed to differentiate between client app authentication and user authentication, and also between user password access and user JWT access.

What is the proper way to do this? This solution doesn't look clean at all.